# How can I listen and get the position of a modally presented view on Swift

Tags: swift

How can I listen and get the position of a modally presented view on Swift 5? I want to listen the position and change a view's alpha value so I need to listen the view position, even when a user move upside or down manually, i need to get the correct value.

Comment: I think you'd need to write your own view for this. You are not going to be able to do it with the built-in sheet presented view controller because the pan gesture recognizer that the user drags with doesn't belong to you.

Comment: Thank you @matt I tried with constrains but couldn't make it.